# Is the sash title on a WKUserNotificationInterfaceController always all-caps?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I'm building an app for a client that includes lightweight support for Watchkit.

It uses a WKUserNotificationInterfaceController to display local notifications to the user. I have defined both a static and a custom "long look" interface.

I notice that the "Sash" title on the notification is the app display name, forced to all caps.  (This is the colored bar at the top of the notification that has the app icon and app title displayed on it.)

The client's app name is a mix of upper and lower case that is part of their branding. They want the sash name to honor that mixed upper/lower case.

Does anybody know of a way to change the text that's displayed in the notification sash, or are we stuck with an upper-case version of the app display name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i noticed it too, and currently there is no  way to change it, It seems it's managed by Apple and even the title is kinda hidden to be changed.